# Passing information between classes

Tags: c++, class

I am going to try and phrase this properly. Please ask for clarification if needed.

I have a class (we'll call it class a) that has a method that opens a file with ifstream and reads the data from the file. I also have another class (we'll call it class b). I need to take that information from class a and pass into it class b. The method to do this is being called from class b. I thought I could

1. Declare inheritance from a->b
2. Declare friend functions or
3. Just declare a var in class b with class a as the type and run the functions using a.function.

But no matter what, the result always outputs a ? If I run class a by itself, it works fine (reads in the data and outputs the data).

Can you not run functions with infile.get between classes?

Comment: It's a little confusing. Can you show the two cases (works/doesn't work) as `code`?

Comment: The only possible form (excluding globals.. yuck) of information transfer between different parts of code is arguments that get passed to functions. Could you (as egrunin suggested) show the code that does not work as expected (along with the expected behaviour)?

Comment: An example use case would be nice. Ideally, all similar work (opening file, processing data, etc.) should be performed by a single class to keep inter-dependency (coupling) low and cohesion high.

Comment: "I also have another class (we'll call it class b) that I need to take that information from class a and pass into it class b". That statement alone makes this impossible to understand without something **concrete**. Is class b acting as a conduit of data from class a, an end-data-sink? both? neither? Clarification isn't optional here; it is required. Likewise: "But no matter what, the result always outputs a ? If I run class a by itself, it works fine (reads in the data and outputs the data)". Enough euphemisms and generalities (a common source of trouble in the first place). **Code** please.

Comment: The way I'm reading it option 3 is the only one that would work. The fourth option (probably even better), is to declare a and b variables in main. That would be the usual method. But I agree, sample code is needed. Both for us to understand your question, and for you to understand the answers.

Comment: Could you please make and post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to show us?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should have an API defined between your 2 classes. In this case your API can be a method in class B that expects to be called from class A with the data you need to transfer. Something like this:

```
//B header file
struct dataType;
class B
{
    //...
public:
    statusType passData(dataType &x);
};

//A header file
struct dataType   //shared data type between the 2 classes
{
    //internal structure of your data
};

class A
{
    B *objB;   //link to B instance (the receiver)
    statusType acquireData();
};

//cpp file
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
statusType B::passData(dataType &x)
{
    //do whatever you need with the data
}

statusType A::acquireData()
{
    //do your reading from file here into x
    objB.passData(x);
}
```

This example demonstrates the creation of simple interface between A and B classes.
Any other more tight relation, such as inheritance or composition, is possible as well but that really depends on your requirements and implies stronger relationship than you stated. Otherwise it will be (even if works) a design flaw.